# Regular Expression for recognizing non-negative values 1..99

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression which can accept any value from 1 to 99 and does not accept any negative values.  So far, I have:

```
"regex":/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[0-9]{6,}$/,
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
[1-9][0-9]?
```

If you want the whole string to be just a number, you need the ^$ included:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

That depends whether this is the whole regexp, or you want it to be a part of the bigger regexp.

Comment: Better than mine - with the caveat that it only requires a number from 1-99 somewhere on the line rather than matching the whole string.  So, `/^[1-9][0-9]?$/` would be better.

Comment: Just add `^` and `$` to the ends :)

Comment: @J V From what he said, it seems it's a part of a bigger regexp, but you are correct, I'll edit.

Comment: @Derby Yes, it will. It will only match one or two digits, the first being non-zero. For negative numbers, you need -, which the above will reject, as it's not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 1..99, then you probably want to use:

```
/^[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]$/
```

Comment: @Derby: yes - it does not allow '-' as a valid character, so negative values are not accepted.